# Different grid color for different columns

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

How would I go about setting different grid color for different columns?

I know that `table.setGridColor(Color.GREEN);` sets the grid color to specific color, but what about setting color for every line?

I would like my table to have every odd column grid color red and every even column grid color green.

Just go vie an example I want the following

```
G____R____G____R____G
|____|____|____|____|
|____|____|____|____|
|____|____|____|____|
|____|____|____|____|
```

Where R means that the line should be colored red and G means that the line should be colored Green.

This is just for fun and Christmas spirit.

Thanks to anyone for their help.

The only possible solution I can think of is creating a custom
`TableCellRenderer`
and within method
`public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)`
doing
`setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.RED));`
for every odd column and
`setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.GREEN));`
for every even column.

Comment: Override `prepareRenderer()`, as shown in these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjtable%5d%20prepareRenderer).

Comment: @trashgod sorry man, I do not see a single example that can help my case in there. Most of them just suggest using JXTable, and others to use MatteBorder, which I specified however am not too fond of since it does not color the column line itself but rather edge of the cell.

Comment: Instead of one large grid break it up into smaller pieces that you can then color separately.

Comment: @DavidColer and how does one break up grid into smaller pieces? That is my question which I can not solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Table Row Renderering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for examples that show how to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` to highlight the background of different row.

The concept would be similar for column level rendering.